# Drawing multiple shapes using QPainter on the same window?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I am totally new to QT , I was trying to make a simple GUI for a simple drawing app
I created multiple push buttons, each button draws a certain shape, the problem is when
I click on a button to draw a certain shape then clicks on another the previous shape gets deleted, I want all my drawings stored on the same window how can I fix it ? 
any sample codes is appreciated I am still new to QT

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"
#include "dialog.h"
#include<QPixmap>
#include <QLayout>
#include <QLabel>
bool p3=false;
bool p1=false;
QPixmap *pm;
Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
QDialog(parent),
ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
ui->setupUi(this);

}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
delete ui;
}
v;8oid Dialog::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e){

QPainter painter(this);
if(p3==true){
painter.drawLine(10,10,100,100);
painter.save();
p3=false;
}
if(p1){
    painter.drawEllipse(100,100,10,10);

   // painter.save();
    p1=false;
}
}
void Dialog::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
{
 p3=true;
 update();
}


void Dialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
p1=true;
update();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want see drawings you need draw them each time.

```
void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    if(p3){
        painter.drawLine(10,10,100,100);
    }
    if(p1){
        painter.drawEllipse(100,100,10,10);
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    p3 = !p3;
    update();
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    p1 = !p1;
    update();
}
```